# Local branch not created when pulling new remote branches (Git)

Tags: eclipse, git

I am using EGit 2.1.0 in eclipse juno.

A user **X** has created and pushed a branch **FeatureBranch**. Next user **Y** pulls from master. Now in the Remote Tracking the **FeatureBranch** is visible on user **Y's** machine. Now user **Y** want to join the work done on **FeatureBranch**. But the **FeatureBranch** is not automatically available as a local branch. So user **Y** first needs to create a local branch from the remote **FeatureBranch** (else all commits will end up being seen as detached heads).

Why does user **Y** have to manually create a local branch from the remote branch before being able to commmit/push on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how git works.  Remote branches are read-only.  If you want to automate the `git checkout --track` or whatever it is you want to do, you could certainly script it.

Comment: -1 – only partially true: remote branches are read-only, but if you use git properly this will never impede you. There is nothing to be scripted.

Comment: @Chronial, he could certainly want to script the initial checkout of new tracking branches to match remote branches.  Why not?

Comment: I don’t understand what you could script about that. Assume there is a  new remote branch with name `newbranch`, then you can just run `git checkout newbranch`. What would a script make simpler about that?

Comment: You could make a replacement for `git remote update` or `git fetch` that fetches, and then automatically checks out tracking branches for new remote branches.  I don't know if I'd do it myself, but it could certainly make things easier for version-control-phobes (read: hardware engineers).

Comment: That’s right, but that’s not what the op is complaining about – egit will *actually* check out remote branches and pretend like everything is fine. It will then silently go to detached HEAD state once you commit anything :).

Comment: Ah gotcha - I don't know anything about eclipse.  That's probably where I went off the rails.  OP did accept the answer, which is a bit confusing.